# prevent Shared session with multiple browser windows

Tags: asp.net, session, browser

I am developing asp.net application. When I debug my web application on local host, it takes two different session id for two different browser windows. But when I publish it on server and open application on my computer session is shared with all browser windows.
I want two different users to login in two different browser. Is it possible? If not than what is the reason it is taking two different sessions for my local host and one when I publish it on server

Many Thanks,

Ni

Comment: sessions being shared between multiple browsers usually means the session cookie is broken and gets the same session ID assigned to everyone.

Comment: Sorry when I said multiplet browsers, I meant multiple window of IF not different browser. Is that what you meant? IF yes than what can I do about it? Thanks-Ni

Comment: From one browser, not really. Cookies are shared between browser windows, unless one or more of the windows are in "porn mode" (aka icognito/private browsing).

Answer (score 3):

That's by design, and there's nothing you can do about it. You cannot login to the same site with two different accounts at the same time, regardless if you're using 2 windows or 2 tabs in the same window (assuming same browser type/vendor).

You would have to develop the site specifically to support managing more than one different accounts at the same time (Google does it, but with limitations). The way I see that done is by defining a record for the USER and separate records for ACCOUNTS that belong to that user. Then you can have the user login, and ASK them - per page - which account they want to manage, maintain that state - per PAGE - and have some kind of account-switch mechanism (e.g. dropdown) so that they can switch accounts. Again, this would be per page, involving viewstate (or similar mechanism), and session would still be shared.

Another way to make this possible is to have some kind of account identifier in URL; e.g.

```
http://mysite.com/account-1234/default.aspx
http://mysite.com/account-5678/default.aspx
```

This would allow a single user to manage multiple accounts. If you would want to maintain separate logins, you would have to authorize based on the account-id part in URL, and  you would have to maintain separate auth cookies (with different cookie names; e.g. "auth-1243" and "auth-5678") - which means you'd have to do some work at auth level. And, again, the session would be shared, so you wouldn't be able to store a single account-specific data in it (it would have to be in "account" collection, retrieved based on the id from the cookie). The URL requested would always have to match the cookie, or you would probably use cookie-path to create that restriction.

I personally like the second option, and I think it's doable; only I would probably use URL-ENCODED email address in the URL, as that's easier to remember (even though longer), or username (if you manage those on your site, since those would be unique). +1

Comment: Thanks Hari..this is great.. Just one thing, Why there are two different sessions in local host(debug mode in my computer) for two IE windows (not Tab)?

Comment: Is one of those IE windows running in incognito mode (Toos > InPrivate browsing)? If so, perhaps this would be the reason (I didn't test this). Otherwise, I'm pretty sure something is confusing you to think that: browser shares and OVERWRITES cookies as it gets them from sites. Each cookie CAN (does not HAVE TO) be set to relate to a PATH (aside from relating to a DOMAIN that issued it) - so, if you are talking about two apps (localhost/app1 and localhost/app2), and have those paths set on those cookies, this would explain it.

Comment: Perhaps refreshing the page of the "previous" browser, or its debug information was a factor? Or, what exactly made you conclude that?

Comment: Humm this is interesting. I am not running browser in private browsing mode. I am storing session id in database and when i run my application on local host(debug mode) it stores two different session id. but when I published my application on server,it has one session id for two different IE windows. SO I dont know what triggers that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem.  I have an ASP.NET application.  To enable multiple sessions in different windows, I use different collections stored in session variables labeled by an applicaition generated session number to hold the context of each window.  A bit of code, but it works.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a complete answer, but it could be improved with some sample code or pseudocode to illustrate your strategy