# Emulating multiple clients to a web server

Tags: session, browser, webserver, emulation, benchmarking

If possible i want to use my computer to emulate multiple clients (like TPC-W) on a web server, i tried to use Htmlunit however when i created two WebClient() they had the same login session (when one logged in the other was logged in as well in a stateful bean, it causes the second one to crash because the login form disappears after the logging in).

The reason i'm not using TPC is because i want to benchmark on my own web pages. I'd like to know if it is possible to use TPC to emulate my own pages or a library/trick that can do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the answer to my question was written in the following question.

[prevent Shared session with multiple browser windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131765/prevent-shared-session-with-multiple-browser-windows?rq=1)

The answer is: multiple logins in a single session. Thanks goes to user191966 for the answer.